# populate spinners with details how

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm including a spinner for my app which lets the user choose what kind of workout, for that matter, he wants.

For example I have this:

```
 Endurance               > Bench press
 (workout type)          Leg Curl ups
                           ....,etc.
                         (workout name)
```

How will I view the list of workout names upon clicking the workout type? BTW, workout names are accompanied by check boxes, so it needs to be editable/removable in the future. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. What's the question?

Comment: My question is how will do it? Since i'm a newbie to android, I just don't know where to start.

Comment: BTW, I have thought of including a separate table for the workout types then will just call them by using foreign keys. do you think it will work? i'm not familiar with spinners, but I do need them in my app.

Comment: Your idea sounds fine. It is just way too broad of a question to ask on here. You need to think about what you want and give it a go then ask a more specific question. If you have something particular then me and other SO members will be more than happy to help. The first place to start is [The Docs](http://developer.android.com/index.html)